why my django registration view not able to add new users?
I have below DRF APIView. I am building a basic user registration with OTP
class RegisterView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'registration.html')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = RegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()

            # Send verification email with OTP
            otp = generate_otp()
            user.otp = otp
            user.otp_expiry = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=5)
            user.save()
            send_verification_email(user.email, otp)
            return Response(
                {
                    'message': 'Account created successfully. Please verify your email.',
                    "status": status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                }
            )
        return Response(
            {
                'message': serializer.errors,
                "status": status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            }
        )

The above function is calling below two functions
def generate_otp():
    return str(random.randint(100000, 999999))


def send_verification_email(email, otp):
    subject = "Verify Your Email Address"
    template_name = "email_verification.html"
    context = {"otp": otp}

    html_content = render_to_string(template_name, context)
    text_content = strip_tags(html_content)

    msg = EmailMessage(subject, text_content, to=[email])
    msg.content_subtype = "html"
    msg.send()

register.html
<form id="register-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>

<script>
    document.getElementById('register-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(event.target);
        const jsonData = {};
        for (const [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
            jsonData[key] = value;
        }

        fetch('{% url "register" %}', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.status === 201) {
                alert('Account created successfully. Please verify your email.');
            } else {
                alert('Error creating account: ' + data.message);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert('Error creating account: ' + error.message);
        });
    });
</script>

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('register', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
]

project: urls.py
path('auth/', include('user_authentication.urls'))

when I call http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/register
I am seeing below errors in my console
Forbidden: /auth/register
[04/Jun/2024 16:38:42] "POST /auth/register HTTP/1.1" 403 45

and on the web page, I see
Error creating account: undefined


Is DEBUG set to True in your settings.py? If not, can you set it to TRUE, then retry and check the error again?

it is enabled, still not resolved

Ensure that the CSRF token is included in the headers of your AJAX request. You can fetch the CSRF token from the cookies and include it in the headers.
For example:
const csrfToken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
fetch('{% url "register" %}', {           method: 'POST',           headers: {                     'Content-Type': 'application/json',                     'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken  // Include the CSRF token in the headers                 },                 body: JSON.stringify(jsonData)           })

yes, this error is now sorted with addition of CSRF in cookies in JS script
